# call Async function inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I am working on a project which is built using express and node js.
I just need to call the async function inside the SetTimeout function (callback)

Here is my Controller File

```js
module.exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Some DB Calls

    setTimeout(() => updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req), 0)

    // Some DB Calls

    return res.status(200).json({ data , msg: "record created successfully", success: true })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error?.message?.includes("Validation error")) {
      return handleErr({ message: "This supplier order id has already been added. Please refresh the page and check further down the screen." }, res)
    }
    return handleErr(error, res)
  }
}
```

Here is the async function in the same controller

```js
const updateWhOrders = async (allOrders, req) => {
  // Some DB Calls using async await
  await SourceOrder.bulkCreate(allOrders.data, { updateOnDuplicate: ["wh_address"] })
}
```

Now I want to ask the difference between these two statements

```js
1. setTimeout(() => updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req), 0)
2. updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req)
```

I just want to call the updateWhOrders function parallel before sending the response back to the API.

Is there any specific reason to use the setTimeout function? Or if I omit the setTimeout function it will behave exactly the same as using setTimeout function?

According to my understanding if I omit setTimeout function it will run in the background by returning a promise. What if I call function(updateWHOrders) inside setTimeout function. What is the benefit? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: Using `setTimeout(func,0)` will simply cause Node to skip this line for now, run all the synchronous code, then run `func`.

Comment: `if I omit setTimeout function it will run in the background by returning a promise` --> No, it returns a Promise anyway (it's an `async` function).

Comment: @JeremyThille. It does not process the function in the background by returning a promise? as async function always returns the promise

Comment: If I omit the setTimeout then it will not call func later by executing all the remaining code?

Comment: What is `rows`? It is nowhere defined...

Comment: @trincot ignore it.

Comment: In that case, could you remove anything from your question that is not relevant?

Comment: @trincot Sure. i will

Comment: Also, I see no code that sets, or modifies `supplierOrder`, yet you report it as the result. Then there is the test on `existingSupplierOrders.length`... As there is no code that sets or modifies `existingSupplierOrders`, why is that test there? It seems there is a lot of noise in this question that makes it hard to see what you are really after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239842/discussion-between-hassam-saeed-and-trincot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `setTimeout` here: it will not execute the callback in parallel, but later, after the rest of the synchronous code has executed.

Instead, if it is the *only* asynchronous task that needs to happen before the call of `res.status(200)`, then use `await`:

```
await updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req);
```

If you have more asynchronous tasks, *and* they are independent of each other such that they could execute in any order -- and don't have to wait for the other's result -- then use `Promise.all`:

```
await Promise.all([
    updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req),
    anotherAsyncFunc(),
    yetAnotherAsyncFunc()
]);
```

### Difference *with* `setTimeout`

You asked for the difference between these statements:

```
setTimeout(() => updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req), 0)
updateWhOrders(req.Orders, req)
```

The first will not call `updateWhOrders` now, but will schedule it for execution after all synchronous code has executed. This could be just after the next `await` has executed, or if there is none, after the `return` has executed. The call stack must become empty first and only then `updateWhOrders` can get executed.

The second will execute `updateWhOrders` immediately.

Neither use the fact that `updateWhOrders` returns a promise, and so this aspect is not well dealt with. You'll want to know when the asynchronous call *inside* `updateWhOrders` has finished its job, and for that you need to do something with the returned promise. That's why you should use either `.then`, `await`, `Promise.all`, ...or anything that deals with that promise.

Comment: Thank you. But updateWHOrders is the independent function that needs to be called without blocking the rest of the code. If I use await then it will execute it and wait for it to complete. Instead, I want to execute in parallel without waiting to complete it

Comment: So you want `res.status(200).json()` to be returned before that `updateWHOrders` is called? Are you sure? Please explain what it is that you want it to be in "parallel" with...

Comment: No. I just want to complete the function updateWHOrders just before res.status(200)

Comment: If you want `updateWHOrders` to run in "parallel" (there is no such thing in JS, but there is asynchrony) with *other asynchronous tasks*, then go for the `Promise.all` version, and call all other async functions in that array that is passed to it as argument, which is the alternative I put in my answer. You need `await` to ensure all those "parallel" tasks have finished before the `return` is executed.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But can you please tell me the difference between the two syntax of the function updateWHOrders that i mentioned already in the question statement

Comment: Added a section to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hassam. `setTimeout` main function is to call a function `asynchronously`. It returns a `promise` and is the replacement of the `new Promise` function in NodeJs.
Coming towards your question, here you don't want to make the `updateWhOrders` function-blocking and want to run it in a seperate thread without blocking other part of code. Although NodeJs is a single-threaded language it uses the same thread to handle synchronus and asynchronous calls and they are handled using Event Loop. To learn more about Event Loop you may watch this video: https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thank you but i need more information